# Grid with flexible-width aligned elements

Tags: css, flexbox

I've been trying to make a responsive grid layout that contains a set of flexible elements without having to put media queries for each order of width.
Basically, here are the "rules" of the grid:

- The elements have a minimum width, but are able to take available space
- The layout will place as much elements as possible on a row. The remaining space will be split among the elements.
- The last elements (on the last and possibly unfilled row) have the same width as the elements on the previous rows.

[I managed to do one system that nearly works with flexbox](https://jsfiddle.net/xeat4gvf/1/).
The only problem is that the last element takes all available space instead of being aligned with the previous elements.

```
#b {
    border: 1px solid black;

    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#b div {
    border: 1px solid red;

    flex-grow: 1;
    flex-basis: 200px;
    display: inline-block;

}
```

Is there a way to do that with only CSS ?
Thanks in advance !

Comment: I've seen this request before and, as far as I know, you can't do this with `flexbox` without a hacky workaround.

Comment: Flexbox has no grid notion. Maybe with [CSS Grid](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-grid-1/)?